# Save image without asking confirmation using browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk fails

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm trying to save image file(jpeg) without asking for confirmation to **save the image** when "save as" option is clicked by right clicking the image.

Having set the known properties for the firefox profile, the confirmation dialog still occurs and could find the solution.

However with the same properties the **open file** for excel works.

```
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\mydownloads\\");
    fxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream");
    fxProfile
            .setPreference(
                    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
                    "text/csv, application/pdf, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml");
    fxProfile
            .setPreference(
                    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                    "text/csv, application/pdf, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,image/png,image/pjpeg,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/excel");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile);
```

- selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
- java version "1.8.0_31"

Answer (score 0):

1. You're setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` twice.
2. You shouldn't set `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile`

Working code example in PHP (settings are the same regardless of the language):

```
$profile = new FirefoxProfile();
$profile->setPreference('browser.download.folderList', 2); # download to dir
$profile->setPreference('browser.download.panel.shown', false); # don't show info bubble
$profile->setPreference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp');
$profile->setPreference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'application/x-octet-stream,text/csv'); # skip confirm
$capabilities->setCapability(FirefoxDriver::PROFILE, $profile);
```